# OpenGL GLSL not suported 3.30

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

My shader has "*#version 330 core*" on first line but it says

```
0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
```

And there is output from console after running "*glxinfo | grep 'version'*"

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

EDIT: I know it says "shading language 1.3" but it too says "core shading language 3.30"

PS: I am using C# and OpenTK

Comment: Did you request a Core context from the OS?

Comment: How can I do that? There is one main problem - before reinstalling my Debian it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I had to change my constructor to

```
using(GameWindow window = new GameWindow(800, 600, GraphicsMode.Default, "...", GameWindowFlags.Default, DisplayDevice.Default, 3, 3, GraphicsContextFlags.ForwardCompatible))
```

PS: [This helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767467/glvertexattribpointer-raising-impossible-gl-invalid-operation)

Comment: Even though this is working with your case, the right answer is to check whether your PC supports the right OpenGL version if not then setting new OpenGL version changes nothing. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899973/cant-compile-samples-of-opengl-superbible-7th-unresolved-external-symbol/31902855#31902855

Comment: @CroCo Mesa supports newer features (such as GLSL 3.30) in the core profile only. Changing the OpenGL version and profile can absolutely change things.

Comment: Please mark your question as resolved by selecting your own answer as the right answer.

Comment: I know but I need to wait until tomorrow (2 days from posting)